# Javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I found this function for a drupal tutorial. Can someone explain me, why the following javascript does not work within my wordpress installation and may give me a solution?

```
;
(function ($) {
 "use strict";
  var $corn = $('.corn-anchor');
  $corn.each(function(idx, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.once('corn-animation', function() {
      $(window).on('load', function() {
        new Waypoint({
          element: el,
          handler: function(direction) {
            $el.toggleClass('corn-animated', (direction == 'down'));
          },
          offset: '85%'
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I want to use it to toggle some section-wrappers to animate the elements within those wrappers by using css transitions with the .corn-animated selector. I am using the waypoints plugin. I don't even get an error message in the debugger, although no toggleClass is added when I scroll down to the element with the class corn-anchor.

Comment: You are declaring an anonymous function without ever calling it?!

Comment: Yeah, seems to be obvious, but I am afraid, I am very new to this and just trying to learn by doing it :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing ever runs the code in the function. Looking at it, the last line should be

```
    })(jQuery);
//    ^^^^^^^^---- *call* the function, passing in `jQuery`
```

not

```
    });
```

Also, make sure that's loaded by a `script` tag at the **end** of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag (and after the `script` tag that includes jQuery). Otherwise, it'll run too soon and not find any `.corn-anchor` elements.

If you don't control where the script ends up (since you're using  Wordpress), **instead** of changing the last line, change the first one:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
```

That calls `jQuery`, passing in that function; jQuery will call the function later (passing itself in as the first argument) when the HTML has been parsed and the DOM is populated; it's an alias for [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready).

Comment: Hi T.J, thank you so much for your response! I used most of the last night to get a solution for this and was not able to get it work. After using jQuery (function) ($){ the debugger gave me some errors, I had to change $el.once('corn-animation', function() { to $el.each(function() { and voila, it works! :) May you explain me why $el.once('corn-animation', function() did not get the job done? However thank you, thank you, thank you very much!

Comment: @DoUtDes: `$el.once('corn-animation', ...` hooks up an event handler for the `corn-animation` event that removes itself the first time it's triggered. Frankly, the code doesn't make a lot of sense, as what's inside it is hooking up a handler for the `load` event on `window`. That seems like a very odd time to be doing that.

Comment: you probably right, since I had to modified it (with your help) + it is copied out of a drupal tutorial, where the function just looks a little bit different, since they are starting with Drupal.behaviors.name = {
attach: function (context, settings) { my posted code...

But with this two first lines the code is unable to work, cause Wordpress does not know something like Drupal.behaviors.name